# Should I use -webkit-box-shadow in my CSS or just box-shadow?

Tags: css, webkit

I noticed Google does not add `-webkit-box-shadow` in the CSS, for example:

[image]

This is the CSS for this element:

```
.RNNXgb {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%);
    height: 39px;
    width: 690px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I am not sure should I include `-webkit-box-shadow` in my box shadow? So should I use:

```
.my-container {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%);
}
```

or should I use:

```
.my-container {
       box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgb(64 60 67 / 16%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

-webkit-box-shadow works on backdated browsers . box-shadow works on almost all modern browsers. But since you don't know which browser will access your website. It is always safe to use both together. There will be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit`, `moz`, etc, are prefixes used for styling websites for the browsers **you** want to support. Most of the modern browsers nowadays support both `-webkit` and the prefixless styling. So it is up to you to choose which one you want to use. If you want to support **very very** old versions of Google Chrome, you should use `-webkit`; as well as prefixless styling so that it supports new browsers as well.

So for the sake of ease, just use normal `box-shadow` as all browsers support it nowadays.